# $Q(\pi)\neq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

How cani demonstrate that $Q(\pi)\neq \mathbb{R}$, that is the field of rational functions of $Q(x)$ evaluated in $\pi$ is a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A counting argument would work ($\Bbb Q(\pi)$ is countable, although it requires a bit of work to show, while $\Bbb R$ is not, which also requires some work to show). Is that allowed?

Comment: Do you know about the distinction between countable and uncountable sets?

Comment: It does not contain $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @orangeskid How do you know? ;)

Comment: @M Winter: OK, I don't know. But it's true if $\pi$ is transcendental. If it is algebraic, then $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ would not contain $\sqrt[n]{2}$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: It's common knowledge that $\pi$ is transcendental, but hard to prove. One can avoid this fundamental fact by reasoning in the alternative case too: even if $\pi$ *were* algebraic, we couldn't have $\Bbb Q(\pi)=\Bbb R$, either by cardinality argument, or the fact $\Bbb R$ contains algebraic elements of arbitrarily high degree.

Answer (score 7):

If $p\in\Bbb Q(x)$ and $p(\pi)=\sqrt 2$ then $p(\pi)^2=2$, which is impossible because $\pi$ is not algebraic.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the OP knows that $\pi$ is not algebraic.

Comment: Against the general advice of this forum, the OP asked a homework-type question, but gave us no hints what he knows.  So he has no basis for objecting to anything used in an answer.

Comment: @GEdgar I wasn't objecting to the answer (I upvoted it in fact) - I was just pointing out that it relies on a nontrivial fact.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ... OK.  I also upvoted this.  My first reaction to the question was that $\sqrt{\pi} \not\in \mathbb Q(\pi)$.